# How do I remove noise from this audio file?

Tags: audio, noise-reduction, speex, audacity

I am uploading an audacity project with 2 tracks, the 1st one contains a "bitbit" sound resulted from Speex echo cancellation. I tried to remove the sound using Audacity noise cancellation, didn't work. Tried equalizer to cut off some high frequency sounds, worked but somehow degraded the sound quality. Please help how I can clear the noisy audio without significantly degrading quality.
If Audacity doesn't work, any C/C++ library can also be used.
[Audacity Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bydl_9DgdvZjSkFwaEpoRnE0RWs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Noice Reduction effect from the effect menu.